# Get back to US from Canada without passport

Tags: usa, air-travel, canada, tsa

Im 18, never had a passport, and crossed US-Canada Border last month by car using my Vermont Enhanced Drivers License. My plan was to drive to Alaska and fly home from there, but an unexpected family event requires me to prematurely go back to the US in one week and I am too far from the US border to expedite my trip and get to an American airport (currently high up in Yukon). Can I plead my case at a Canadian airport and use my EDL for them to verify my citizenship? Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could get a domestic flight within Canada that takes you closer to Vermont, and then get across the border there.

Comment: How high up in YT? If you go far enough there aren't any roads anymore. It's only a 12 hour drive from Whitehorse to Anchorage. So if you are actually somewhere that there are roads, you can get out easily enough.

Comment: Further to @GregHewgill's point:  Montreal is well-served by domestic Canadian flights and is only a two-hour drive from Burlington.

Comment: I can't find a road in Yukon more than 14 hours from a US airpot !?!

Comment: @MichaelHampton: if you're suggesting reentering the US at an unauthorized road crossing, isn't that an offense?

Comment: You can't make it to Alaska in _a whole week_? How were you planning to get to a Canadian airport? Can you just fly to another Canadian airport near the border and drive over?

Comment: @smci No.  Michael is suggesting Laurence drive (optionally with an internal to Canada flight to get closer) to a normal border crossing and return to the US using his EDL.  The EDL is legal for land crossings, but not air travel.

Comment: @smci how do you get anything like that from what I wrote?

Comment: @MichaelHampton: simply asking. If you simply meant to say "there are road crossings between YT-AK", then fine. It simply wasn't clear. Thanks DanNeely for clarifying.

Comment: @Strawberry, there are roads in Yukon that aren't on any map.  There are even more roads that specifically aren't on Google.  Many of these roads aren't roads you'd want to drive quickly on.  Even for the roads that *are* on the map, Google tends to be wildly optimistic about driving speeds.

Answer (score 23):

You will almost certainly be unable to board a flight to the US with your EDL, since it is explicitly prohibited by the [Western Hemisphere Travel Initiative](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/western-hemisphere-travel-initiative), which brought EDLs into being in the first place.

You could in theory get an emergency passport at a US consulate, but from your description of your location you seem to be closer to airports in Alaska than you are to any US consulate.  Besides, the nearest consulate is in Vancouver, and if driving to the US border is going to take more time than you have then so is driving to Vancouver.